# Finding isomorphism between two groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I'm reading [Vern Paulsen's notes.](https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/grouprepn.pdf)

I don't know how can I show  $\Bbb R^*/\Bbb R^+$ and $\Bbb Z_2$ are isomorphic because I'm not sure about operation of $\Bbb R^*/\Bbb R^+$. Should I consider it as multiplicative group while $\Bbb Z_2$ is additive group?

In addition I appreciate any help or hint for constructing a bijective homomorphism between them.

Thanks!

Comment: The author defines the groups $\Bbb R^*$ and $\Bbb R^+$ on page $3$. They are mutiplicative groups.

Comment: To prove the claimed isomorphism, try finding a surjective homomorphism $f$ from $\Bbb R^*$ to $\Bbb Z_2$ such that the kernel of $f$ is $\Bbb R^+\!$.$\;$Hint: "a negative times a negative is a positive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $\operatorname{sgn}\colon \mathbb{R}^*\to \{-1,1\}^\times$; note that $\{-1,1\}^\times$ is a group as it is finite and closed under multiplication; by the rule of signs, $\operatorname{sgn}(xy)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)\operatorname{sgn}(y)$, and thence $\operatorname{sgn}$ is a group homomorphism; moreover, $\operatorname{sgn}$ is surjective; then (first homomorphism theorem), $\mathbb{R}^*/\operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{sgn})\cong \{-1,1\}^\times$. Now, $\operatorname{ker}(\operatorname{sgn})=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^*\mid\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1\}=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\{-1,1\}^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ (*), and finally $\mathbb{R}^*/\mathbb{R}_{>0}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

---

(*) $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}_2\to \{-1,1\}^\times$, defined by $0\mapsto 1$ and $1\mapsto -1$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the operation that you should consider on $\Bbb R^*$ is the multiplication. And the operation on $\Bbb Z_2$ is induced by the addition on $\Bbb Z$. Now, consider the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^*/\Bbb R^+&\longrightarrow&\Bbb Z_2\\\lambda\Bbb R^+&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }\lambda>0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$and prove that it is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Should't we first prove that $\mu \in \lambda\mathbb{R}^+\Rightarrow \operatorname{sgn}(\lambda)=\operatorname{sgn}(\mu)$?

Comment: Yes, that is a necessary first step :) Also, the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function must be defined strangely here if we want it to behave additively; probably we should be thinking of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the multiplicative group $\{-1,1\}$ instead.

Comment: My answer was inconsistent and I have edited it.

Comment: I think we can define the function as $1$ if $\lambda \gt 0$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: @usereb That is not a group homomorphism.